# Index of Object from LDAP Query

Tags: vba, excel, collections, ldap

I run an LDAP Query in VBA and obtain an Object with the match using GetObject:

```
Set colOU = GetObject("LDAP://OU=LazyPeople,DC=somecompany,DC=com")
colOU.Filter = Array("user")
```

I have been looping through the `colOU` using a For Each statement:

```
For Each objADObject In colOU
```

However, what I need to do is present a ListBox with the name of each user from the `colOU` and have the user choose an entry.  Then I want to go back to that instance, (`objADObject`) from `colOU` that corresponds to the user selection and manipulate the properties.

What I would like to do is store an index for each `objADObject` in each entry of the ListBox, and use that index to recall that instance from `colOU` after the user makes a selection.  However, I cannot find a way of accessing `colOU` items by index, (.Items, .Item, .Members, .Count, and UBound generate errors).  I have been unsuccessful in trying to cast or convert `colOU` to a collection as well.

Any suggestions?

Also, how can I investigate an object in VBA to find out if can be enumerated, (what in .NET I would call an IEnumerable).

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code? Initial thought, maybe just make a local collection/array to keep track of all this stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have figured this one out.

Apparently, you can take the colOU object and do a:

```
Set objADObject = colOU.GetObject("user", <RelativeDistinguishedName>)
```

and it will set the objADObject to the correct user object.  So, I assigned `objADObject.name` (which is the RelativeDistinguishedName) to a hidden column 2 of the ListBox.  When I retrieve the value from the hidden column, I can just pass it as a variable to `colOU.GetObject` and I will have a reference to the correct user object.

Huzzah!

However, I would still like to know if `colOU` can be enumerated if anyone knows the answer.